# Add and remove data to table - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm making a simple name and email list - by table in React. I want to fetch data from server, and next can add or remove persons dynamicly. This is my first steps with React, so I have a problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from "./Form";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            people: [],
        };

        this.addPerson = this.addPerson.bind(this);
    }

    addPerson(name, email) {
        this.state.people.push({name: name, email: email});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPeople();
    }

    getPeople() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({people: response}))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <Form/>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>LP</th>
                        <th>USER</th>
                        <th>EMAIL</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={person.email}>
                                <th>{index + 1}</th>
                                <td>{person.name}</td>
                                <td>{person.email}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )

                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default App;
```

and Form component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name,
            email: this.props.email
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.addPerson = this.addPerson.bind(this);

    /*    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this); */
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value})
    }

    addPerson(name, email) {
        this.props.addPerson(name, email);
        this.setState({name: '', email: ''});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input id='name' type='text' name={this.state.name} placeholder='Name...'/>
                <input id='email' type='text' email={this.state.email} placeholder='Email...'/>
                <input onClick={() => this.addPerson(this.state.name, this.state.email)} type='submit' value='submit'/>
            </form>
        )
    }

}

export default Form;
```

And now i want to can add data to table for form submit, or if I want, delete data for table. I got stuck in this moment...

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, Form component, line 8. For this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rewrite your code as follows.

I will make `Form` component as [*uncontrolled component*](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). It means, the form inputs will maintain their own internal states when you change. There is no need to maintain two different sources of data. So I will rely on the parent component `App` state. I also add a form submit handler which will get the inputs values on submit, and then call the `addPerson` method from `App` to add the names to the `people` state maintained by root component `App`.

I added the `deletePerson` method to delete the people from the list. Here are the 2 components looks like.

`deletePerson` method here relies on the fact that people list will have person with **uniq** emails. As you also choose it as `key` props. But you can always change this criterion which will be easy if you understand the current flow of the code.

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      people: []
    };

    this.addPerson = this.addPerson.bind(this);
    this.deletePerson = this.deletePerson.bind(this);
  }

  addPerson(name, email) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      people: [...prevState.people, { name, email }]
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPeople();
  }

  getPeople() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ people: response }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  deletePerson(email) {
    return () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        people: prevState.people.filter(person => person.email !== email)
      }));
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form addPerson={this.addPerson} />
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>LP</th>
              <th>USER</th>
              <th>EMAIL</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={person.email}>
                  <th>{index + 1}</th>
                  <td>{person.name}</td>
                  <td>{person.email}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={this.deletePerson(person.email)}>
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;
    const email = form.elements["email"].value;
    const name = form.elements["name"].value;
    this.props.addPerson(name, email);
    form.reset();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
        <input
          id="name"
          type="text"
          defaultValue=""
          placeholder="Name..."
        />
        <input
          id="email"
          type="text"
          defaultValue=""
          placeholder="Email..."
        />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Please check [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9r9692m77) demo.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a deletePerson function to your App component, and then pass deletePerson and addPerson as props to your Form component, like this:

```
<Form addPerson={this.addPerson} deletePerson={this.deletePerson} />
```

Then make use of them in your Form component.