# How can I import projects (React) from a public sandbox to a local project folder?

Tags: reactjs, sandbox

There are a lot of examples on StackOverflow written in CodeSandbox for React, and I am wondering how to download the files into a local folder that I could edit and alter in an editor like Atom.

For example, I want to use the Sandbox example (https://codesandbox.io/s/k9r9692m77) given as an answer in this question ([Add and remove data to table - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919115/add-and-remove-data-to-table-react/51919213#51919213)).

The only way I can think of doing this is by a similar process below:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

Then copying and pasting all the files individually into `my-app` and doing `npm install`, then `npm start`. But I do not feel this is an efficient way to do it, especially when the projects have a lot of individual files.

I have not worked much with React, or Sandbox, so I get a little confused when in Sandbox I do not see an App.js file for a React project, yet the project still runs (I am guessing this is through the index.js file). This might only apply to the Sandbox code I linked in this question.

Let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can download the project as a zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weItD.png)

1. Extract it
2. open in terminal
3. npm i
4. npm run start and it should pop up
   in your browser at localhost:3000

In the projects package.json, there is a field called main which you can use to set the entry point of the application. This can be used instead of having App.js. More information available [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Comment: It worked! Two questions, 1) Even though I did not set this up with create-react-app, is this still considered a React application? 2) In the case of the code from the sandbox that I linked in my question, is the entry point index.js? So if I wanted to it to be App.js, would I have to create a new file called App.js, move relevant code there, then change the entry point to App.js?

Comment: 1. Yes this is a react app. Even though you did not set it up with create-react-app, it was created with create react app.

2. If you want to change index.js -> app.js, you'll need to do a few few steps.
 i) "npm run eject" and accept the consequences
 ii) in "config/path.js" change "appIndexJs: resolveApp('src/index.js')" to appIndexJs: resolveApp('src/app.js'),

Comment: in Sept 2020 i cannot see the download zip link as per your screenshot !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

hover on the downward arrow you will get Export To Zip option
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to click on the hamburger icon at the top left next to my user name, then click on `File` -> `Export to ZIP`.

[image]