# How do I create a dynamic React table that also manipulates a dynamic JSON file?

Tags: json, reactjs, dynamic

I have seen a lot of examples and tutorials for dynamic React tables, and also examples that import JSON data into a react table, but I have not yet found one that dynamically changes a React table and a JSON file.

I am basing my code off this one (https://codesandbox.io/s/k9r9692m77), which is the accepted answer to a StackOverflow post ([Add and remove data to table - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919115/add-and-remove-data-to-table-react/51919213#51919213))

I would like to be able to submit data through the UI with a "submit" button like the one in the example, and that data be displayed in a UI table, but I would also like the data that is added to the table to also be added to a JSON file.

**Example:**

There are two fields, one for the **USER** and one for **EMAIL**, so for two entries I would get a table like the one below:

```
|------------------|-------------------|------------------|
|       USER       |      EMAIL        |       Actions    |
|   Bennie Factor  | bennie@factor.com |       Delete     |
|   Horace Cope    | horace@cope.com   |       Delete     |     
|------------------|-------------------|------------------|
```

Which would then produce a JSON that looks something like:

```
{"data": [
    {"name": "Bennie Factor", "email": "bennie@factor.com"},
    {"name": "Horace Cope", "email": “horace@cope.com"}
]}
```

If I then added the user Jay Walker with an email of jay@walker.com and clicked submit, the new table and json would be:

```
|------------------|-------------------|------------------|
|       USER       |      EMAIL        |       Actions    |
|   Bennie Factor  | bennie@factor.com |       Delete     |
|   Horace Cope    | horace@cope.com   |       Delete     |
|   Jay Walker     | jay@walker.com    |       Delete     |     
|------------------|-------------------|------------------|
```

And:

```
 {"data": [
    {"name": "Bennie Factor", "email": "bennie@factor.com"},
    {"name": "Horace Cope", "email": “horace@cope.com"},
    {"name": "Jay Walker", "email": “jay@walker.com"}
]}
```

The process would be:

1. You type data into the relevant boxes
2. Click submit and that data is then displayed in a table, and also appended to a JSON file

I would also like the ability to delete the entry from the JSON file through the UI table. Basically anything that can happen to the UI table will also happen in the JSON (e.g. adding an entry to a UI table will then add the same data to a JSON, and removing an entry from the UI table will also remove the same entry from the table).

Please let me know if more information is needed to clarify my question.

Comment: The code in sandbox is already doing that only, right?

Comment: @Thinker If it is adding the submitted data to a json, I do not know where that json file is located.

Comment: The API endpoint just returns JSON data, and that does not mean it saves the data in JSON format. Most likely it saves the data to a database and the API takes that data and it returns a JSON formatted response. React is a client framework (*it can render in server too, but that's not the point here*) which means that you won't be able to save anything to the client directly. Even if you want to save your data to a JSON file (*which is high unlikely, go for a database*), then you'll have to create an API that will do the CRUD operations.

Comment: @ChristosLytras So in this case I cannot save a JSON locally, and should instead have the UI table data sent to a database and retrieve it from there in JSON format?

Comment: @W.Churchill yes, you create an API. The API server code will access the data using a database and it will return JSON formatted data or it will accept JSON data to write to the database. Search for `CRUD` `MySQL` `JSON` `API` in `PHP` or other languages (*you'll find PHP installed to almost every hosting provider*) and you'll find some nice examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything happens in JS is stored in memory by default, as opposed to written to some "file" on disk. For security reason web browsers normally don't have write access to users' local disk unless **explicitly granted by user interaction**.

You can allow user to download those data in memory to a `.json` file on disk by clicking a button. The trick is to generate a dataURI link on the fly:

```
class App extends Component {

  // ...

  saveAsFile() {
    const str = JSON.stringify(this.state.people);
    const dataUri = "data:text/json," + str;
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "table.json";
    link.href = dataUri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <button onClick={this.saveAsFile.bind(this)}>download</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-cherry-0tke6

Another option is to use the [Native File System API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/). But I won't dive into it here since it's still experimental and not a web standard.

Comment: Thank you, your answer not only made me aware of the local memory, but helped me realize why it is not that trivial to allow a web browser to access local files. I am now wondering where the "local memory" in the browser is stored and how that is accessed? For example, the entries entered into the table that you provided in your sandbox, I am guessing the information is accessed through the React state, which can be accessed with a state variable (hook)?

Comment: I don’t really get what you are asking. Your question can be answered differently on many levels. The short answer: where - in memory, that hardware thing; how - through “random access”. So which level of detail are you asking about?

Comment: From the browser level where the React App is. For example, sometimes when you go to a website it still has information from a previous visit until you clear your browser history. I am wondering where that "data" is, and how it can be accessed within a React script.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for (Web Storage), "Local Storage" and "Session Storage". https://www.positronx.io/store-react-form-data-or-state-in-local-storage/